How to select SSH key by fingerprint from ssh-agent, while using `IdentitiesOnly yes` option?
This would be useful in situations where:

serving SSH keys via KeePass where there is no file path, and
there are otherwise too many keys: as ssh tries all of them and some hosts are configured to allow a small number of tries (so a "Too many authentication failures" error is given)


Its an irritating problem, but I don't think this is viable as a solution unless you're going to wite a complex wrapper around ssh. Just create a ssh_config with an alias for Host and the relevant value(s) for Hostname and IdentityFile.

Regarding "not viable": do you mean that putting ssh keys into KeePass is unviable due to the problem I'm having?

You can define the identity to be used in the ssh config via the corresponding public key. So something like:
Host x.y.z
  IdentityFile ${HOME}/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub

This works although the identity will be presented by an agent. So the corresponding identity File does NOT have to be present in ~/.ssh/.
This is somewhat unexpected but works fine.
At least this works for me using gpg-agent.

Thanks! To clarify the mechanics of this: ssh needs a fingerprint to select the private key from ssh-agent. A fingerprint is a shorter identifier generated from the public key. So, all one needs to do is link to a public key with the IdentityFile directive and it will simply work.
